# fitSystemWindows with windowTranlucentStatus and windowTranslucentNavigation makes Toolbar too tall

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app bleed under the status bar and the navigation bar. I got the layouts to work using fitSystemWindows = true with just the status bar translucent but when I make the navigation bar as well, the toolbar appears to react as if it needs to fill under the status bar and the notification bar.
[The toolbar appears to function normally when in landscape for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3ycO.png)
This double "translucent" bar effect also makes the NestedScrollView extends beyond the bottom of the page. I am also not sure how to make the FAB fit.

On another note, I originally wrote the layout with a CoordinatorLayout. This added the extra problem that the NestedScrollView then scrolls up to the bottom of where the toolbar should be, not where it is. I think, however, that the NestedScrollView respected the bottom screen boundary properly with CoordinatorLayout.

Here's the xml for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="74dp"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/nav_color_1_bright"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            app:navigationContentDescription="@string/open_nav_menu"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_dehaze_white_24dp"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:onClick="createNew"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/darkAccent"
            app:fabSize="normal" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I apply the following 'Light Theme' to the Activity programmatically.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name ="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/lightPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/lightAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/lightPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButtonStyleDark</item>
</style>
```

Here's a preview of the layout: (bigger version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Mp4.png))

[image: Toolbar goes under status bar and thinks it needs to go under navigation as well]

Comment: Try to wrap your ConstraintLayout into CoordinatorLayout and Toolbar into AppBarLayout and set height for toolbar `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: Wrapping them did not appear to make any meaningful change. I messed around with applying fitSystemWindows on just the wrapper and that makes the toolbar "normal" sized but lacking the top padding that fits the status bar. Using ?attr/actionBarSize for the Toolbar does the same thing.